# Copy data to another excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that selects a range of cells, erases the cells, sorts the data by alphabetical order and saves the file.

I need the macro to copy the selected range of cells to another excel sheet but I am not able to create the code.

The code of my macro is:

```
Sub SAVE1()
'
' SAVE1 Macro
'

'
    Range("B8:K8").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
        ("B7:B85"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("B8").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Please let me know if you have some ideas.

Many thanks for your help.
Joao

Comment: what is the range of cells from "Sheet1" you want to copy ? what is the name of the Destination Sheet ? what cells in the Destination Sheet ?

Comment: If you want code to *copy* the *selected* range (as you stated above) then you can simply use `Selection.Copy Destination:=....` as outlined here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760.aspx

Comment: Based on the 'selects' in that code it looks like you recorded this, why not just record the copy action as well to get your answer?